# Eclipse project configuration when using m2e

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

We use maven/m2e/eclipse combo for our work. We start with importing master maven pom file in eclipse and our projects get imported. Our source control system is set up to ignore eclipse generated project files as we don't want to check in anything generated. It all works nicely and not problems on this end.

What we would like to do is set up some common eclipse preferences for all the projects to ensure standard coding style across all developers and follow java best practices. Example is reorganize imports setting in eclipse, reformat code when file is saved, and standard line widths (we prefer 120 characters as against standard 80 eclipse default)

It seems like m2e can be configured to generate some of these settings using project configurator, but could not find any examples.

Any thoughts how we can achieve this functionality? It would be much nicer to have project specific entries generated from maven pom configuration and everyone will share same settings automatically.

I don't mind writing some code for the m2extension, but I am not familiar with eclipse guts and don't know what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about doing this through m2e, but you can Export your code formatter from Eclipse, and instruct new developers to import it when they get set up; I've done exactly this in the past and it leads to a consistent coding style (and sometimes grumpy developers, be warned!).

In Eclipse, go to

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter

and create a profile that defines just how you like your Java to look.  Then select Edit on that profile, and you'll see an option in the top right to Export, which will produce an XML file.  Check this into your repository somewhere or otherwise distribute it to your developers, and they can import it in a similar way.  Then each time they press ctrl+shift+f they'll all be formatting the same way.

More help here: [Eclipse Indigo Java Code Formatter](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/codestyle/ref-preferences-formatter.htm)

Comment: Sorry, that's for Eclipse Indigo - it's been that way for as long as I can remember, so it should be the same for all recent versions